# Filter nodes out of a XmlNodeList (Sytem.Xml. XmlNodeList)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, filtering

I need the most efficient way to filter out Nodes from a  XmlNodeList.
The  XmlNodeList is what i get back from dtSearch.
The list contains a list of items that are found on a specified searchPhrase.
I want to filter out all items that are not belonging to the website i want to look on.
The information about what website the result has been found on is stored in the path of the result and I can access it using:

```
// Get a list of Item nodes
XmlNodeList list = xmlResult.SelectNodes("/sitecore/result/item");

foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in list)
{ 

   XmlNode thisScPath = node.SelectSingleNode("scPath");
   if (thisScPath == null)
     continue;  
}
```

Let's say i want to filter out all Nodes with a scPath containing string "xxy", is it possible to do this before i enter the foreach in which i walk through all the nodes in the list? For example, can I do this with Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add predicates to the XPath expression, e.g.

```
/sitecore/result/item[scPath!='xxy']
```

will find all item nodes that don't have a child node "scPath" with a value "xxy".

Comment: Okay, good. Is it also possible to make sure the path is not present in the scPath Node? For example, I want all items that contain the following scPath = "xxx/yyy/zzz/" to be filtered out. So also an item with the path "xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/aaa/zzz" will not be in the list.

Comment: Never mind my last question, I thank you alot for this solution!